# jscrollpane - Allow content to expand over scroll area?

Tags: jscrollpane

Im using the jscrollpane jquery plugin. My content are images that expand when you mouse over them, and shrink back to normal on mouseleave. What I need if for the images to be able to expand over beyond the scroll bar and remain visible while expanded.

By giving the images a z-index I can get them to expand over the scroll bar handles, but im struggling to get them to expand any further.

If I set a number of elements to having overflow visible I can get it to work, but then I have browser scroll bars at the bottom of the screen.

Can I have the images visible when they expand but no browser scroll bars? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from:
http://groups.google.com/group/jscrollpane/browse_thread/thread/8073378d51551efa

Hi,

If I understand correctly you want your images to expand out of the
bounds of the scrollpane "box"? That won't be possible in a simple manner.

A workaround might be to do something like this:

```
* On mouseover clone the image that is rolled over and attach the
  clone to the body with position: absolute.
* Use jQuery to figure out the position of the image you cloned with
  respect to the body (a loop with offsetParent will be your friend
  here).
* Apply this position to the cloned image so that it is sitting
  directly above the original image then expand it.
* Listen for the mouseout event on the cloned image and when this
  happens the shrink the cloned image and then remove it from the body.
```

Hope it helps,

Kelvin :)